# Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I am trying to implement a simple change for an apex class in production. I have the proper class and proper test class. The test class runs successfully in sandbox without errors, but apparently the error is coming from the TestHelper default test class in Salesforce. When trying to deploy in production it throws the error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createUser(Id, String, String, Date, Integer) from the type TestHelper"

I've tried the usual of changing the method it references to public static void, but to no avail, it throws errors in code

This is my test class:

```
@isTest
private class OppLineItemInvntryBO_AType_OppStge_Test {   

    @testSetup public static void setup() {
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile 
            WHERE Name = 'profile1' LIMIT 1];

            Date myDate = Date.newinstance(2019,07,01);

        User testUser = TestHelper.createUser(p.Id, 
               'company1','legalentity1',myDate,327001);
```

And this is my TestHelper class:

```
public with sharing class TestHelper {
  public static User createUser(Id profileId, String company) {
    Integer rnd = getRandomNumber(10000);

    User user = new User(
      Username = 'john.doe@acme.com' + String.valueOf(rnd),
      Email = 'john.doe' + String.valueOf(rnd) + '@acme.com',
      LastName = 'Doe',
      FirstName = 'John',
      Alias = 'JD' + String.valueOf(rnd),
      ProfileId = profileId,
      LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            CompanyName = company);
    insert user;
    return user;
  }

  public static Integer getRandomNumber(Integer size){
    Double d = math.random() * size;
    return d.intValue();
  }
}
```

The full error is this:

API Name - OppLineItemInvntryBO_AType_OppStge_Test
Type - Apex Class
Line - 14
Column - 36
Error Message - Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void createUser(Id, String, String, Date, Integer) from the type TestHelper

Comment: There's no such thing as "TestHelper default test class in Salesforce". It's your own code (some other developer at your org created it). You're free to modify it to fit your needs. Perhaps you need to deploy the sandbox's version of TestHelper class to production too?

Comment: That was it! thank you so much man!

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking the createUser method with 5 parameters in OppLineItemInvntryBO_AType_OppStge_Test class where as in the TestHelper class , the createUser method accepts only 2 parameters. Thats why you are getting this error. Try to invoke the method with correct parameters.

Comment: oh darn it, I pasted the old TestHelper class, mine already has the correct parameters!